# ActiveRecord many-to-many table with association type field - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I'm building a Rails photo gallery app which allows users to create private galleries and invite users to the gallery under different permissions (i.e: viewer and editor).

I am thinking that galleries_users table will be required to resolve the many-to-many relationsip:

```
user_id | gallery_id
--------------------
1       | 4
--------------------
2       | 4
```

But should I store the association permission type? Can I just add a `permission` field:

```
user_id | gallery_id | permission
---------------------------------
1       | 4          | edit
---------------------------------
2       | 4          | view
```

Is this on the right track?

I have also seen the Rolify gem but using that would mean adding a user to a gallery (via method above) and the adding a role separately through Rolify's interface. Unless there is a way I can skip the first step of adding a user to a gallery and treat the role as the association?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using many-to-many relationship you can try for one-to-many relationship. Having said that I mean to keep the relationship of owner and gallery separate, that is don't mix owner of gallery with invited users as it may create problems in future implementations, and try to maintain invited_users in another table.

1) Owner-gallery -> one to many relationship

Table1: users

Table2: gallery

2) Invited users:

Table3: invited_users

You can create this table with columns like gallery_id, view_permission_user_ids_arr, edit_permission_user_ids_arr etc.

So for each gallery you can have array of user ids having view/edit permissions easily available.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, I forgot to mention that there are no gallery owners. The user who creates the gallery should automatically be assigned the editor permission. This means that mixing invited users with creators is not an issue

Comment: @slehmann36..In that case having Many-to-Many relationship seems to be better approach. And regarding permission field, I think it is required to have such distinguishing factor, so having permission field is must or you may think of two separate fields as edit_permission, view_permission etc. which may help you in querying db.